# How do I create a gauge in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I'm looking for a view that I can put on an activity that displays as a gauge, with tickmarks, and allows me to set a value to change where the needle is pointing. Just like a speedometer!

Thanks!

Comment: ISBN 978-0-470-56552-0 Has an excellent Compass example as well as much more very useful examples. It was on page 109 that I really found the answer to my question!

Comment: can you share the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't such a control in the SDK.  You'd have to create your own.

**Edit**: [Here's](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) some information on creating custom controls.