# Meter Gauge Android Shake Meter

Tags: android, shake, gauge, meter

How do I go about creating a Shake Meter similar to a Meter Gauge in Android?
Can I make use of a progressbar to do it?

Hope someone can give me a guideline on how do I go about creating the Meter Gauge upon detecting the shake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This librairy can help : https://github.com/github/gauges-android

Or this thread if you wanna do everything by yourself : [How do I create a gauge in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335560/how-do-i-create-a-gauge-in-android)